# Illustrator envelope distort tool alternative

Tags: adobe-illustrator, software-recommendation, apple

Is there a similar tool to envelope distort on Illustrator available for an iPad or iPhone app, or even an online editor?

I have some great graphic design apps for my iPad and iPhone but nothing has the disort options like Illustrator on my desktop. I really need this and would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

I do believe Affinity Photo for iPad has mesh warp and perspective distort, but I'm not sure how much vector editing capabilities it has.